# Meaning of "Studying electronics as long as I could pick out my own books"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Somebody told me:

> Studying electronics as long as I could pick out my own books.

but I didn't understand what he means.

I can guess that studying electronics takes too long time. Am I right?

Comment: You probably should add more context. I find it hard to understand the meaning without some sentences from the preceding part of the talk.

Comment: @CopperKettle He just started his speech by the sentence and then, He said another sentences teaching me something about electronics. The sentences are related to electronics and are not related to the first sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any other context, what your friend is saying in this **conditional sentence** is that he **doesn't mind studying electronics**, the condition that he is imposing is that he can **use the books that he wants to use to study** as opposed to books which may be prescribed by a **course syllabus**

**As long as** is the **phrase** that introduces the condition and functions as an **if**.
**As long as** has the meaning

> Studying electronics **as long as** I could pick out my own books.
>
> Studying electronics **only if** I could pick out my own books.
>   Studying electronics **provided that** I could pick out my own books.
>   Studying electronics **on condition that** I could pick out my own books.

In your example, it is not a **description of time duration**, which might be

> **as long as** the sun shines

The **condition** for your friend's studying is that he gets to use the books **he chooses**.

Maybe he thinks the course books are not very good and he knows of better sources